# Counting multiple ranged criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, countif

this is my first post on this forum, so it's probably presented in a very bad way. I am using Excel 2007 to collect some data for my thesis. I have recently learnt how to nest COUNTIFS inside SUMPRODUCT to search for multiple criteria where one of these criteria is a range rather than a constant. However, the same formula does not work if I need to search for multiple criteria where two (or more) of the critera are ranges rather than constants.

Say I have three adjacent columns A-C in Excel, where A is called "Fruits" and containing various fruits, B is called "color" and C is called "poisonous?", containing only the values "yes" or "no". How do I add up all items which are EITHER an apple OR a pear from column A and EITHER green OR red from column B and not poisonous from column C?

In this simple Excel sheet, the correct answer is 4, but the following formula gives me 1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,$E$2:$E$3,B:B,$F$2:$F$3,C:C,$G$3))
```

[image]

where the critera refer to arrays that I have put up manually outside.

I have been searching both the net and the forum for answers, and I find dozens of related posts, some perhaps even identical ([Countifs with multiple OR criteria ranges](https://superuser.com/questions/1133754/countifs-with-multiple-or-criteria-ranges)), but I still don't manage to find it out... Running late on time with my thesis, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If your requirement is to count Fruits by color and the number how many are poisonous and total of poisonous Fruits in Table format, The Answer is ready with me, please confirm !

Comment: @RajeshS, I do not quite understand; I would like to count the number of apples and pears (not bananas) that are either green or red but not poisonous. Since all apples and pears in my table are green or red, the correct answer should be 4, since there are 2 non-poisonous apples and 2 non-poisonous pears. However, be using the formula given in my post, I get the answer 1, which is wrong. Do you know how to provide the correct formula? In more general terms, how I can use two ranged criteria in the same formula?

Comment: (1) Please don’t call [SE] (of which [SU] is a part) a “forum”. It is a question and answer site.  (2) You say “I have recently learnt how to nest COUNTIFS inside SUMPRODUCT to search for multiple criteria where one of these criteria is a range rather than a constant.” It would have been nice if you had shown a working example of that. I guess I have figured out / remembered what you are talking about, but I didn’t immediately recognize it by your description. If you had shown an example (and/or linked to an explanation with examples), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2a) people would have been able to learn something *from your question,* and (2b) people would have been able to work on developing an answer to your question by building on what you already know, rather than starting from scratch and/or trying to reconstruct what you already know (reinvent the wheel).  (3) You might want to develop less-uniform data. (3a) All of your apples and pears are either red or green. And conversely, all your red or green fruit are apples or pears. Therefore you get things like [Rajesh S’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1326319/150988#1326367), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  which actually counts the non-poisonous apples and pears (without regard to color), and it gets the right answer because the data aren’t robust enough. (3b) Looking at your non-poisonous fruit, you have exactly one red apple, one green apple, one red pear, and one green pear — and no other colors or fruits. That sort of uniformity makes it easy for a wrong formula to get the right answer.  (4) [We prefer that you not post screenshot of spreadsheets (or, in general, images of text).](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)  Post a textual representation of your data,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table) or the [Plain Text Tables generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) site if you want.  (5) Are you sure you’re showing us what you say you’re showing us?  When I try your formula on your data (in Excel 2013), I get a result of 2.  If you must post a screenshot of a spreadsheet, please leave the formula bar in the picture, so we can know for sure what formula you have in your sheet.

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain better. As for nesting countifs in sumproduct: In the worksheet in the screenshot above, if I want to find out how many apples are red OR green, but not poisonous, I could use: =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,F2:F3,C:C,G3)) This would give correctly give me 2. However, if I want to find out how many pears OR apples are either green OR red AND not poisonous, I cannot use: =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2:E3,B:B,F2:F3,C:C,G3)), since this also gives me 2 (not 1, sorry), rather than the correct 4. I need a single formula that gives me the correct answer 4, and furthermore

Comment: Continued: and furthermore, this formula must allow me to drag the criteria into the formula by referring to cells (like E2:E3 or F2:F3), rather than naming the criteria inside quotation marks, since the search I want to run will range over 25 different values in one of the criteria and 16 in the other criteria. There will be a third criteria that is a constant, like in the above formula, which refers to non-poisonous... Perhaps I should make a new post and try to present my actual data... Or perhaps piko's suggestion with whitelist and blacklist could work, I will try it out...

Comment: However, @piko suggested that I refrain from running whitelist searches on columns, but that is exactly what I need to do. All of the ranges that I need to search are entire columns, stretching over 2000 rows down. I need to search three such columns simultaneously in a single formula, and two of the three criteria, as said, spans over multiple values with an OR logic... I hope this is correctly described.

Comment: @Pjossemannen, sorry I didn't know there were so many lines. What I meant is: it is generally a good practice not to use a whole column (e.g. `B:B`) in calculations. A column contains thousands of lines (1 million in Excel 2016), so even if your data takes 100k rows (which is really huge), you don't need the remaining 90%.

Comment: @Pjossemannen, also, please check my [second answer](https://superuser.com/a/1326808/888507) and tell us if it works for you! I believe it is what you need :-)

Comment: Thanks @piko, I will check it out. And that's very good advice you give about not referring to entire columns, I could easily change my formulas from A:A to A1:A3000 etc., which will work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to nest anything. The function `SUMPRODUCT` is a very powerful one, that allows you to either count or sum based on very complex conditions. It supports both the logic AND and OR operators.

### TL;DR version

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$10="Apple")+($A$2:$A$10="Pear"))*(($B$2:$B$10="Red")+($B$2:$B$10="Green"))*($C$2:$C$10<>"Yes"))
```

---

### Long version (sorry...)

You should really learn how to use this function, because it's very useful and can save you a lot of time. Here is a quick and dirty guide on how to use it, but I advise you to keep some kind of test file with simple examples, like the one you provided, so that you can experiment with it. Don't hesitate to split the different problems you're trying to solve.

Basically, a `SUMPRODUCT` contains several *members*, each of them being a condition. If you multiply these conditions, you obtain a logical AND. If you add these conditions, you obtain a logical OR.

It's much easier with an example! So here is the breakdown of the final formula using your fruits example.

**Note:** to make things easier, I used a table names `Fruits`, which allows the use of named ranges and improves readability.

[image]

So here is how it works. Your first condition is actually a logical OR (you want either Apples or Pears, since a fruit can't be both. So the formula (1) has 2 members, or 2 conditions: Fruit = Apple, Fruit = Pear.

`(Fruits[Fruit]="Apple")` will return `TRUE` if it's an apple, `FALSE` otherwise. By summing this to the 2nd member (`(Fruits[Fruit]="Pear")`), you will obtain an array of 0 and 1. The logic is the following:

- False + False = 0
- True + False = 1
- True + True = 1

Then, the `SUMPRODUCT` will sum all the elements of this array (0 and 1). Which is basically the same as counting elements. The result is 8, as expected (cell D14).

The 2nd condition (color) works exactly the same. If you wanted to include a 3rd color (e.g. "orange"), you would simply add a new member in the equation with a `+`.

The 3rd condition is more simple, you just have 1 criteria. I used the `<>` sign on purpose, to show you that you can also exclude elements. In the formula (1), you could have used for instance `(Fruits[Fruit]<>"Banana")`.

**Important:** Please note that in a `SUMPRODUCT`, when there is only one member (like in the 3rd equation), you need to convert the result to a number. Remember: the `SUMPRODUCT` creates an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. You can do this easily by using the `N(...)` function, or alternatively writing `--(...)`, which will transform `TRUE` into 1, and `FALSE` into 0.

Now, these 3 conditions work individually, but we want to combine them into 1 formula. And since we want each of these 3 conditions to be true (fruit, color and poisonous), we need to create a logical AND. This can be done the same way we did our OR, but this time we will use the multiplication (`*`):

- False * False = 0
- True * False = 0
- True * True = 1

For our 3 conditions, we simply use the 3 individual formulas we wrote earlier, and put them inside a `SUMPRODUCT`. These 3 members must be encapsulated by parenthesis, and separated by a `*` (we basically multiply them).

Here are the final formulas, for you to try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Fruits[Fruit]="Apple")+(Fruits[Fruit]="Pear"))
=SUMPRODUCT((Fruits[Color]="Red")+(Fruits[Color]="Green"))
=SUMPRODUCT(N(Fruits[Poisonous]<>"Yes"))
```

And the final one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Fruits[Fruit]="Apple")+(Fruits[Fruit]="Pear"))*((Fruits[Color]="Red")+(Fruits[Color]="Green"))*(Fruits[Poisonous]<>"Yes"))
```

---

Side notes:

- Each condition that you test (e.g. Color = Red) must be encapsulated between parenthesis: `(Fruits[Color]="Red")`
- The order of the parenthesis is very important if you have OR conditions. For instance, the equation `(X and (Y or Z))` is not the same as `((X and Y) or Z)`.
- You can use the classical operators to test a condition: = for equal, <> for different, > and < for greater/lower than, >= and <= for greater/lower or equal.
- We used the `SUMPRODUCT` to count, but we can also use it to sum things. If one of the member of the equation doesn't have a `=` sign, then the values are taken into account (see the example below, where the column G is summed).
- The criteria `"Apple"` can be replaced by a reference to a cell, which itself can be a dropdown menu. It's a better practice to use variables, instead of writing text directly inside a formula.
- `SUMPRODUCT` can be a resource intensive formula, since it's making multiplications and sums... Depending on how many conditions you're testing, how big the data set is, and how many times you're using a `SUMPRODUCT`. For more simple conditions, `SUM.IFS` is probably faster.
- `SUMPRODUCT` also supports partial text search, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer, I will experiment with this. It is the final formula I'm interested in, since it combines everything into one formula. However, both the ranged variables I have contain very many elements. It would be like having 24 fruits and 16 colours in the final formula. Instead of enclosing each condition in " " , is it possible to refer to a range of cells where the critera are listed, so that I can just "drag" them into the formula, like:  ...((Fruits[Fruit]=F1:F24))* ((Fruits[Color]=G1:G16))...etc. I don't get this to work for more than 1 ranged condition.

Comment: Indeed, it might not be the best solution if you have lots of criterias... I have found another solution that works very well, I'll post it as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution, that works very well and is much more suited to the OP's need to have a list of possible criteria. I adapted the piece of code found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859526/9596610).

You have basically 2 ways of counting values:

- Either using a "whitelist", to list the acceptable values, using `ISNUMBER`
- Either using a "balcklist", to exclude the unacceptable values, using `ISNA`

**Whitelist:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (ISNUMBER(MATCH(Fruits[Fruit],Whitelist[Fruit];0)))
    *
    (ISNUMBER(MATCH(Fruits[Color],Whitelist[Color];0)))
    *
    (ISNUMBER(MATCH(Fruits[Poisonous],Whitelist[Poisonous];0)))
)
```

**Blacklist:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (ISNA(MATCH(Fruits[Fruit],Blacklist[Fruit],0)))
    *
    (ISNA(MATCH(Fruits[Color],Blacklist[Color],0)))
    *
    (ISNA(MATCH(Fruits[Poisonous],Blacklist[Poisonous],0)))
)
```

I strongly advise you not to use this on a column, as it might be resource intensive. I haven't tried it on a very big list of values, but feel free to share your results!

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I entirely understand this,
but it seems to be possible to get the answer with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$3,$A$2:$A$10), COUNTIF($F$2:$F$4,$B$2:$B$10), COUNTIF($G$3,$C$2:$C$10))
```

To try to explain: as we know `COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10, "Red")`
(or, equivalently, `COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10, $F$2)` counts the red fruit,
yielding a count of 3. 
Similarly, `COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10, "Green")`
(or, equivalently, `COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10, $F$3)` counts the green fruit,
yielding a count of 5. 
So it’s intuitively tempting to try to use `COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10, $F$2:$F$3)`
to count the fruit that are red or green. 
This doesn’t work by itself, but we can make it work by doing

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10, $F$2:$F$3))
```

as an array formula, or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10, $F$2:$F$3))
```

as a normal formula. 
One of the nice things about `SUMPRODUCT` is that
it is designed to handle arrays automatically,
so you can use it to do things with arrays without needing array formulas.

But the above formulas are doing exactly what the preceding discussion
would lead you to expect: they are adding 3+5 and getting 8. 
This is important: they are adding an array of two numbers,
because we are looking at two colors. 
This gets us into trouble when we’re looking for different numbers of values
in the different columns.

`COUNTIF($E$2:$E$3, "Yellow")`, `COUNTIF($E$2:$E$3, "Red")` and
`COUNTIF($E$2:$E$3, "Green")` don’t seem, at first, to make as much sense;
they have the values 0, 1 and 1, respectively. 
But this means that `COUNTIF($E$2:$E$3,$A$2:$A$10)` produces an array
of nine numbers, namely:0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 and 1. 
Guess what? 
The sum is still 8.

Remember how `SUMPRODUCT` works. 
`SUMPRODUCT(X11:X14, Y11:Y14, Z11:Z14)`, for example, equals

( `X11` × `Y11` × `Z11` ) +
                ( `X12` × `Y12` × `Z12` ) +
                ( `X13` × `Y13` × `Z13` ) +
                ( `X14` × `Y14` × `Z14` )

so it needs to have array arguments that are the same length. 
Two, two, and one is a problem; 15, 26, and some other number is a problem. 
Nine, nine, and nine is good.

Now look at the `X`, `Y`, `Z` example, but make these substitutions:

- `X11` → `A2` is one of the fruits we are looking for,
- `Y11` → `B2` is one of the colors we are looking for,
- `Z11` → `C2` is “no”,

and so on down. 
Since TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0, each row of the `SUMPRODUCT` matrix is 1
if each column contains a value we are looking for (because 1×1×1=1),
and 0 if the row is not acceptable in every column. 
So we have a list of nine 0s and 1s, which we add.

Answer (score -3):

Since this is the key issue,"**I would like to count the number of apples and pears (not bananas) that are either green or red but not poisonous**."

Therefore I would like to suggest solution in Table Format meets your requirements.

*Check the Screen Shot:*

[image]

Write this formula in E2: `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10, "="&$D2,$B$2:$B$10,"="&E$1)`

**Note,** Fill the Formula one Cell Right then One Row Down, you get number of Apple and Pears.

Write this formula in G2: `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10, "="&$D2,$C$2:$C$10,"=No")`

**Note,** Fill the Formula one Row Down, you get number of Non-poisonous Apple & Pears.

Finally, Sum the Non-poisonous Column.

Comment: thank you, this works of course. However, my question about the pears and the apples was just an example, my actual data files contain completely different and much more complex information. For example, the range of the first criterium (the equivalent of the apples OR pears) spans over 15 different values, and the range of the second criterium (the equivalent of red OR green) spans over 26 different values, so in total 15 X 26, rather than 2 X 2. What I really need is a single formula, rather then breaking it up in several... In this example, a single formula to give the answer 4.

Comment: Actually, no, this doesn’t work. OK, yes, it produces the correct answer (4), but it’s getting the right answer for the wrong reason; by coincidence. Specifically, it is counting the non-poisonous apples and pears, regardless of color. It’s obvious, when you look at it: the bottom-line answer is `=SUM(G2:G3)`, where the formula for `G2` and `G3` looks at Columns `A`, `D`, and `C` — where Columns `A` and `D` are fruit (apple/banana/pear) and Column `C` is poisonous (yes or no). It doesn’t look at Column `B` (color), and the intermediate results in cells `E2:F3` are not used in the final answer.

Comment: @Pjossemannen,, nice to hear from you, If it works for you then please either up vote it or accept as answer. And I've solved the problem on the basis of information you have passed to us. Regarding your actual data, only I could say unless the data is not available I can't say what to do next. if you feel mail me, find my ID in profile.

Comment: As Scott said, the final result doesn't take into account the color criteria, so this solution doesn't work.